# Calling a Select/Option from Functions.php in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm not very familiar with PHP and Wordpress, but I've been trying to work this out for a while now and to no avail. I have a HTML Select menu with options in Functions.php (which is used as an easy editor) and I want to call the selection of that menu on another page. This is the select menus:

```
    <div class="form-field">
  <tr class="form-field">  
      <th scope="row" valign="top">  
          <label for="mkb_apartment_promotion"><?php _e('Promotion'); ?></label>  
      </th>  
      <td>  
    <select name="c3m_mbe_promo">
        <option value="0" >Select</option>
        <option value="10pct" <?php selected( $c3m_mbe_promo, '10pct' ); ?>>10% Off</option>
        <option value="20pct" <?php selected( $c3m_mbe_promo, '20pct' ); ?>>20% Off</option>
        <option value="limited_avail" <?php selected( $c3m_mbe_promo, 'limited_avail' ); ?>>Limited Availability</option>
    </select>
          <span class="description"><?php _e('Select the promotion on this apartment'); ?></span>  
      </td>  
  </tr>  
</div>
```

And this is where I'm trying to call it:

```
 echo '<img src="'.$_POST['c3m_mbe_promo'].'" class="promotion_overlay" />';
```

I'm basically trying to get it so that you choose the type of promotion on the product, and which will call an image URL, and then the URL of the image gets inserted into the src="" to overlay the product's image. Hope that makes sense?